# Apache ErrorDocument absolute path

Tags: apache, http, mod-rewrite, error-handling, mod-alias

I'm trying to use the same 404 ErrorDocument for a domain and all its subdomains,
The subdomains all have their own directory in the /var/www/ path

the Apache ErrorDocument directive expects a relative path (relative to the current directory) but I want it to
go to /var/www/ErrorPages/404.html from all directories/subdomains

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311411/apache-errordocument-with-absolute-path) asked in 2010 but it does not eleborate on the solution, I have tried Alias and couldn't get it to do what I want.

Example 1:
file `http://example.com/doesnotexist.txt` requested

-> show `/var/www/mervin/ErrorDocuments/404.html` as response

Example 2:
file `http://subdomain.example.com/otherimaginaryfile.txt` requested

-> show `/var/www/ErrorPages/404.html` as response

Virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.mervinkoops.net
ServerAlias mervinkoops.net *.mervinkoops.net spirecoder.com www.spirecoder.com *.spirecoder.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/mervin
ErrorDocument 404 /ErrorDocuments/404.html
Redirect 404 /favicon.ico
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} public\.mervinkoops\.net [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} pma\.mervinkoops\.net [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /PHPMyAdmin/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.mervinkoops\.net [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /website/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mervinkoops\.net [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /website/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.spirecoder\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /website/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} spirecoder\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /website/$1 [L]
<Directory /var/www/mervin/>
allow from all
Options -Indexes
RewriteBase /
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

How would I go about doing this?

Other info: Apache2.2, MOD_ALIAS working, MOD_REWRITE working, Symbolic Links enabled

Answer (score 8):

I setup a test configuration on one of my dev boxes - the main thing I notice missing from yours is a Directory declaration for your error docs!!

This works for my setup:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName stackexchange.nexus.local
        ServerAlias serverfault.nexus.local

        DocumentRoot /Data/vhome/stackexchange.nexus.local/httpdocs

        HostnameLookups Off
        UseCanonicalName Off
        ServerSignature On

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error_log
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access_log combined


        Alias "/ErrorPages" "/Data/vhome/stackexchange.nexus.local/ErrorPages/"
        ErrorDocument 400 /ErrorPages/bad_request.html
        ErrorDocument 401 /ErrorPages/bad_request.html
        ErrorDocument 403 /ErrorPages/bad_request.html
        ErrorDocument 404 /ErrorPages/bad_request.html


        <Directory /Data/vhome/stackexchange.nexus.local/httpdocs/>
                AllowOverride All
                Options +ExecCGI -Includes
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
                RewriteBase /
        </Directory>


        <Directory /Data/vhome/stackexchange.nexus.local/ErrorPages/>
                AllowOverride All
                Options +ExecCGI -Includes
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        #RewriteEngine On
        #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} public\.mervinkoops\.net [NC]
        #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
        #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} pma\.mervinkoops\.net [NC]
        #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /PHPMyAdmin/$1 [L]
        #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.mervinkoops\.net [NC]
        #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /website/$1 [L]
        #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mervinkoops\.net [NC]
        #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /website/$1 [L]
        #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.spirecoder\.com [NC]
        #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /website/$1 [L]
        #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} spirecoder\.com [NC]
        #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /website/$1 [L]


</VirtualHost>
```

Get your Alias/ErrorDocs stuff working for your main domain, then if there is still trouble with the aliases, we can work on that [though I have a feeling that once you add the directory - everything will fall into place! ;) ]

-sean

Comment: Your example does not seem to work the apache log just gives an error_docs does not exist error. There is only one Vhost for which I need this, it has 2 subdomains that rewrite to directories directly under /var/www/

Comment: I do want the domains/subdomains to be in 1 <VirtualHost> directive,
I have added my <VirtualHost> definition to my post.

Comment: I edited my entire answer to avoid any confusion with stuff that won't work.  Please re-read.

Comment: I tried your VHost suggestions, I get a 404 (it still searches the relative path 'currentdirectory'/ErrorDocuments/ instead of /var/www/mervin/ErrorDocuments/

Comment: How did you verify that mod_alias was working? - to me it is pretty suspect right now.